Using the user class in the route, how to return response if not found
My laravel returns a 404 when it doesn't find the user in the bank. I remember that there is a way to do this check and return a response, but I don't remember and I can't find it. Can anyone help me?
I'm not going to put the entire function code

Route::post('/users/validate-pin/{user}', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController::class, 'validatePIN'])->name('api-users.validatePIN');



public function validatePIN(User $user, Request $request)
    {
        try {
            if(!$request->user()->can('Validar PIN')){
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Não autorizado',
                    'error' => 'Unauthenticated',
                ], 401);
            }

            ...

        } catch (\Throwable $error) {
            dd($error);

            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Erro no sistema',
                'error' => $error,
            ], 500);
        }
    }


You could not type hint $user, and add the $user instantiation inside the function. Right now validatePIN(User $user, Request $request) automatically checks for an existing user and instantiates it, or throws a 404 if the user isn't found.

you should list your route parameter in validatePIN() method after your Request dependencies.
Change this line of code..
public function validatePIN(User $user, Request $request)

Instead use this code in place of the above mentioned code.
public function validatePIN(Request $request, User $user)

Also remember to import the User model to the top of the script for implicit model binding.
For more information see the official docs for route parameter and dependancy injection.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#parameters-and-dependency-injection
